# adding mongodb data value filed using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello all I have to need to add two field values {type:Number} of one collection from MongoDB using node js
and store the result in the same collection of MongoDB

1st node js query fetching the data value from MongoDB inside my controller.
2nd trying to add the fetched value.
3rd store the result in the same collection of MongoDB using node js.

1). Node js

```
var levelScoreQuiz = require('../models/levelscoreSchema.js');
try{


         var queryObj = {};
         var projection = '-id child.quiz_level.score_pre';
         var projection2 = '-id child.quiz_level.score_curr'; 


         var a = levelScoreQuiz.findOne(queryObj,projection);
         var b = levelScoreQuiz.findOne(queryObj,projection2);
         //console.log(a);
         //console.log(b);
         var add = a + b;
         //console.log(add);
         res.send(add);


        var userObj = {

        level_pre:req.params.add


        };

        var user = new levelScoreQuiz(userObj);
        user.save(function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err)}
        else{
            //console.log("User score saved successfully");
            console.log("User Previous score saved successfully");
            res.json(result);
        }
      });

    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err);
        return next(err);
    }
```

2). MongoDB Schema

```
var userScore = new Schema({

child: {

    quiz_level:{
        current_level:{type:Number},

            score_pre:{type:Number},
            score_curr:{type:Number}
    }
  }

});
```

3). Result: it shows me object in my browser

```
 "[object Object][object Object]"
```

Comment: What exactly do you wish to add? score_pre and score_curr? you need to extract them from a and b. They are documents.

Comment: both score_pre and score_curr into a variable and then store this added result to MongoDB inside the same collection.

Comment: In which field do you want to store it?

Comment: same field score_pre.

Comment: for example, values store in score_pre is 2 and score_curr are 3 as mention above and I am trying to fetch the data using node js query. And when fetching data is stored in my variable suppose a and b then  I am trying to add both value 2 + 3 and store in the same field score_pre.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var levelScoreQuiz = require('../models/levelscoreSchema.js');
try{


         var queryObj = {};
         var projection = {id: 0, 'child.quiz_level.score_pre': 1};
         var projection2 = {id: 0, 'child.quiz_level.score_curr': 1}; 


         var a = levelScoreQuiz.findOne(queryObj,projection);
         var b = levelScoreQuiz.findOne(queryObj,projection2);
         //console.log(a);
         //console.log(b);
         var add = a.child.quiz_level.score_pre + 
                   b.child.quiz_level.score_curr;
         //console.log(add);
         res.send(add);


        var userObj = {

        child: {quiz_level: { score_pre: req.params.add}}


        };

        var user = new levelScoreQuiz(userObj);
        user.save(function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err)}
        else{
            //console.log("User score saved successfully");
            console.log("User Previous score saved successfully");
            res.json(result);
        }
      });

    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err);
        return next(err);
    }
```

Comment: but it shows me error message{"message":"Cannot read property 'quiz_level' of undefined"}

Comment: BTW, 'child' could be undefined. mongo does not have a schema.

Comment: hello amiram, there is any method which performs both functionalities of Get and Post methods

Comment: get and post of what? where?

Comment: amiram can we perform both get and post method on single controller,

Comment: actually, I have written my code on the single controller as mention above  which router is on Get method.

Comment: Yes. You can even in the same function if in the router you redirect get and post to this function